# Using case statement with Left OUter Join in SQL

Tags: sql, left-join, case

I've following 2 tables
table1

```
Id Name deptId
==============
1  a     d1
--------------
2  b     d2
--------------
3  c     null
--------------
4  d     d1
--------------
```

table2

```
deptId   d_name
==================
d1       accounts
------------------
d2       services
------------------
```

I'm working on a SP where I can pass any one of 3 values for DeptName ( 'account', 'Services', 'All')

If I pass 'All' the I should be getting all records from table1 (using Left Outer Join with table2 which means I should see record **3 c null** too)
For any of the other two values I should get only those records from table1 for which there exists a corresponding record in table1

I'm using following query but its not working in case of specific values for d_name ('accounts', 'services')

```
Select 
======
t1.Id, t1.name, t2.d_name
-------------------------
from 
====
table1 t1
----------
Left Outer Join 
===============
table2 t2 
----------
On t1.deptId = t2.deptId
------------------------
and table2.d_name =
-----------------
CASE WHEN @dname = 'All'
------------------------
    Then table2.d_name
----------------------
    Else @dname
------------------
```

`@dname` is the parameter value that Pass to the SP. currently it works for `'All'` parameter but does not work for specific values('accounts' or 'services'). Not sure where am I going wrong with this

Comment: Please format your code....

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Please read & act on [mcve]. Also, what is your question? PS Since you are always doing a left join of table A, why do you expect not to be returning a left join of table A?